# In MySql, LIMITed correlated sub-query applied to each row of an outer query?

Tags: mysql, limit, correlated-subquery

OuterTable contains a datetime and a fruit type.

```
OuterTable
(
    Day datetime,
    FruitType int
)
```

OuterTable has 8000 rows.

Fruits contains a per-minute count of how many fruits of each type have been eaten around the world.

```
Fruits
(
    Minute datetime,
    FruitType int,
    NumEaten int
)
```

Fruits has half a billion rows.

I want to display the per-minute "NumEaten" counts, for each fruit type, for the past 900 minutes for each "deadline" (or whatever you want to call that) present in the OuterTable.

I'm trying to accomplish the following query:

```
SELECT f.Minute, f.fruitType, f.numEaten
```

for each entry in table `OuterTable`,

to which I want to apply the correlated sub-query:

```
(
    SELECT f.Minute, f.fruitType, f.numEaten FROM Fruits As f
    WHERE f.fruitType = OuterTable.fruitType
    AND f.Minute < OuterTable.Day
    ORDER BY f.Minute DESC LIMIT 900;
)
```

Is there a non-cursor way of doing this?

Comment: Head over to the [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag. MySql doesn't have a `ROW_NUMER()` function.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support LIMITs in sub-queries, period: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-errors.html

Comment: Could you please post the table structure & sample data? Its hard to understand why you would join `OuterTable` with `fruits` based on **apples**.

Comment: I changed my problem statement to make it closer to the real deal, and perhaps a bit more understandable? Essentially I have a table that contains per-minute data for the past 10 years, and an other table coming from another application that tells me for which specific dates I want to know the past 900 data points.